# joomla Category Blog View - Different height on articles

Tags: css, joomla

We are using Joomla 3.3 and have the front page sat up as an Category Blog View. Like this: https://docs.joomla.org/images/a/ad/Table-blog-layout.jpg

We have articles that have different height and we want it to look like this: 
https://docs.joomla.org/images/5/57/Standard-joomla-blog-layout.jpg

(The sorting is not important for us, but hat we don't have any space between the articles)

How can we make this? Settings? Plugin?

We are using protostar template.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at this link: http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/

It should help you do what you want.

**Adding info:**

If your HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="masonry">
   <div class="item">Lorem ipsum</div>
   <div class="item">Neque, vitae</div>
   <div class="item">Incidunt sit unde</div>
   <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
   <div class="item">Lorem temporibus!</div>
   <div class="item">Ab, adipisci</div>
</div>
```

Then the CSS should look like this:

```
.masonry {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 1em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
    column-gap: 1em;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    width: 100%;
}
```

So, the `.item` should be each of the articles and the `.masonry` should be the wrapper around all of the articles.

Comment: Please add some more information rather than a link-only answer.